# Loading aspx page with flushed image in jQuery dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have **page1.aspx** witch is content page. On this page, on click event is triggered:

```
$("#lnkConsent").click(function (e) {
    var dlg = $("#divConsent").dialog();
    dlg.load('page2.aspx').dialog('open');
 });
```

html:

```
<div id="divConsent" title="Consent" class="UniversalDialog"></div>
```

Page **page2.aspx** is an empty page, standard web form no serverside forms or heads:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" >    <div></div>    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code behind on page Page_Load:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.Clear ( );
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.WriteFile ( Path.Combine ( Server.MapPath ( "~/foldername" ), filename);
Response.Flush ( );
Response.End ( );
```

When **page2.aspx** is called through address bar it works correctly: image is displayed
but, when I try to load this page in dialog on **Page1.aspx** result is as is shown below:

[image]

Ofcourse, I would like to show this flushed picture in jQuery dialog loading **page2.aspx** in it.

What is my problem?

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` function you are using expects HTML back, which it never receives. Instead what you might want to do is to create an image tag with source as `page2.aspx` and then set it as a dialog content. Something along these lines (just an idea though, might need some adjustment):

```
$("#lnkConsent").click(function (e) {
    var dlg = $("#divConsent").dialog();
    var image = $('<img src="page2.aspx"/>');    
    dlg.html(image).dialog('open');
});
```